# How to manually call the acceleration function in cocos 2d

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, accelerometer

I would like to make users able to calibrate their accelerometer.
But in cocos 2d (c++) I only know how to call OnAcceleration function automatically.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

in cocos2dx-v2.x，accelerate api is in class CCLayer,you overwrite

`virtual void didAccelerate(CCAcceleration* pAccelerationValue);`

in cocos2dx-v3.x, add EventListenerAcceleration,like

`auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
auto listener = EventListenerAcceleration::create(std::bind(this,&HelloWorld::didAccelerate, std::placeholders::_1));
dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, node);`